# MySQL binary logging

Tags: linux, mysql-replication, mysql5.5, mysql

My server is telling my that binary logging is disabled. When I do a `mysqladmin variables`, I see this: `log_bin                                           | OFF`. This is my configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
# These are some standard (Plesk) options needed:
datadir             = /var/lib/mysql
socket              = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user                = mysql
old_passwords           = 1

# Some general options:
default_storage_engine      = MyISAM
#   We want to make sure eventual data loss is handled correctly:
myisam_recover          = FORCE,BACKUP

# Some security things, to avoid overloading:
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
max_connect_errors      = 1000000

# The important stuff, caching and performance tweaks:
max_connections         = 100
key_buffer_size         = 50M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
sort_buffer_size        = 5M
myisam_use_mmap         = 1
tmp_table_size          = 16M
max_heap_table_size     = 16M
query_cache_type        = 1
query_cache_size        = 64M
thread_cache_size       = 25
open_files_limit        = 65535
table_definition_cache      = 1024
table_open_cache        = 1024

# Although InnoDB is not used, some default optimization options:
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 32M
innodb_data_file_path       = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2

# And finally some logging:
log_error           = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes   = 0
slow_query_log          = 1
slow_query_log_file     = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# Master
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin 
server-id = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
```

So, I did `mysqladmin shutdown` and then a `service mysqld start` and after that `mysqladmin variables`. But it says `log-bin | OFF`? What am I doing wrong?
We are using MySQL 5.5.18-ccl by the way.

Comment: Did you check the error log after restarting?

Comment: Yes, nothing interesting in there. It seems like it doesn't log also.

Comment: Did you check mysql user can write to the logs? That it's using the config file you've shown above?

Comment: Is the user mysql (group mysql)? Should it also be able to read the /etc/my.cnf?

Comment: what happens when you run "SHOW MASTER STATUS;" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mysql is the owner of /var/lib/mysql as follows:

```
cd /var/lib
service mysql stop
chown -R mysql:mysql mysql 
service mysql start
```

Another thing to check for is the presence of another my.cnf

Try the following

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
ls -l my.cnf
```

If a my.cnf file is there, you have found your culprit. Just rename the file

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf_old
```

and then `service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Specify:

```
log-bin-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index
```

Cheers

Comment: Actually I guess specifying this doesn't matter... I take it back.